# Firestore delete entire collection using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete the whole collection using Flutter. So the entire student section I want to be gone.
I only found deleting single documents... and I don't want to delete every document manually.
How do I automate that using Flutter.
Something like this: (just so you know how to attempt this)

```
final firebase = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Students');
await firebase.delete;
```

[image: Here is an Image of my Firestore Console.]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete a collection by retrieving the documents in the collection, loop through each document and call the delete method on its reference.

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// name of the collection to be deleted
String collectionName = "Students";

// Get a reference to the collection
CollectionReference collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionName);

// Delete the collection
collectionRef.get().then((snapshot) {
  for (DocumentSnapshot student in snapshot.docs) {
    student.reference.delete();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete you collection by using `for loop` in `.then`

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Student').get().then((value) {
     for (DocumentSnapshot students in value.docs){
          students.reference.delete();
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I automate that using Flutter?

If there is an event that happens that should trigger the deletion of the collection, then I recommend you write a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) for that. This means that once the event happens, the function is triggered and the collection gets deleted internally.

@KushalHapani solution will work, however, iterating through all documents within the collection and deleting them in client-side code, will work safely **only** for small collections of documents. However, if your collection gets larger, it's recommended to [delete the documents in smaller batches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections) to avoid out-of-memory errors.